# Problem using axios create method and how to use it

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, ip

I'm trying to call public API to get IP address (https://api.ipify.org/) using axios (next app-typescript),

in my file index.ts :

```
import axios from "axios";
export const ipApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://api.ipify.org",
})
```

and when i try to call it :

```
const getIP = await ipApi.get()
```

i got an error Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(223, 47): An argument for 'url' was not provided.

where did i go wrong ? is there something missing? Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a axios instance with `baseURL` set just tell axios to prepend the URL given to the methods called using that instance. In your scenario you are calling the `get()` method without the required parameter `url`, and hence the  error

The correct way of using the instance would be:

```js
const getIP = await ipApi.get("/")
```

Which calls it on the root of the baseURL, essentially calling GET on `https://api.ipify.org/`

You can find the related docs [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance)